# Should I stop trying to retagg the salvaged posts?

Tags: discussion, retagging

I am retagging the salvaged posts. I may not have the know how to edit the meat of the questions but I give it my best.

Should I just stop before I reach my denial limit and lose the ability altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denial limit? You mean the edit ban? Well, you could stop editing, but then you'd be imposing an edit ban on yourself... all in all, I don't see any reason for you to stop editing unless you want to. Editing is optional, of course.

Comment: +1 imposing a self ban would be just as detrimental to the community mwuahahaha I must keep at it. LLPSE